# Jquery Colorbox - retain loading animation until seperate ajax content is ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, colorbox

Take the following example javascript function:

```
function Admin_AccountDetails(UserID) {
    //$.colorbox({ title: "Loading, Please wait", opacity: "0.5", width: "500px", height: "200px" });
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.aspx?ajaxid=3&UserID=" + UserID,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response) {
            $.colorbox({ title: "Account Details (UserID: " + UserID + ")", opacity: "0.5", width: "700px", height: "250px", html: response });
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
            HandleBadAjaxResponse(xhr.status);
        }
    });
}
```

The idea of this function is to load ajax content using our pre-existing functions (note the use of `HandleBadAjaxResponse()` etc) and display the resulting content in a ColourBox div.

This works, but the colourbox isnt shown until the ajax content is returned.

What we'd like to do is have the Colourbox default loading animation up whilst the ajax request is churning away.

**EDIT: Results so far**

at first i tried the iframe method suggested by David:

```
$.colorbox({ iframe: true, title: "Loading, Please wait", opacity: "0.5", width: "500px", height: "200px", html: "&nbsp;", fastIframe: false });
```

This however does not work as intended, yes, the colorbox comes up straight away whilst the ajax request is running, but because we've used `iframe` and `html: "&nbsp;"` the first box does not have the loading gif - the loading gif appears for a split second when the ajax call completes and the box resized, I injected a 2 second delay in my ajax back-end code to demonstrate this problem:

http://www.heavencore.co.uk/filehub/Videos/StackOverflow/WithTwoSecondDelay.avi

Next I tried removing the iframe and html tags from the first box, this works in the sense that the loading giff is visible for the full duration of the ajax request - however it also ignores the width and height parameters and draws a massive colourbox - the size is only corrected when the ajax request comes back, again, another video showing this:

```
$.colorbox({ title: "Loading, Please wait", opacity: "0.5", width: "500px", height: "200px" });
```

http://www.heavencore.co.uk/filehub/Videos/StackOverflow/AlmostCorrect.avi

If i could get it working like [this](http://www.heavencore.co.uk/filehub/Videos/StackOverflow/AlmostCorrect.avi) but with the correct size it's be perfect - any ideas?

The only thing i can think off is to change the default width and height in the ColorBox js file iself:

```
(function ($, document, window) {
    var
    // Default settings object.
    // See http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox for details.
    defaults = {
        transition: "elastic",
        speed: 300,
        width: false,
        initialWidth: "500",
        innerWidth: false,
        maxWidth: false,
        height: false,
        initialHeight: "200",
```

Comment: Good night...any reason why you're NOT using jQuery for these ajax calls?

Comment: It’s a pre-existing application and I don’t fancy rewriting 4000+ lines of javascript :)

Comment: @DavidL Although, if you can show how to use colorbox's ajax functionality but still call our `HandleBadAjaxResponse(xmlHttp.status)` function (with the ajax status code as a parameter) I can certainly look into it.

Comment: Try changing this `$.colorbox({ title: "Loading, Please wait", width: "500px", height: "150px", html: "&nbsp;" });` to this `$.colorbox({ title: "Loading, Please wait", width: "500px", height: "150px"});`

Comment: @RodrigoAssis Cheers, I tried that already, unfortunately it seems that without specifying `href` or `html` colourbox waits for content and ignores the `width` & `height` parameters meaning you end up with a massive colour box until the ajax content comes back :)

Comment: @HeavenCore A shame that you have to deal with all that legacy junk :(.  That said, I posted a solution that I think will solve your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The following $.ajax solution should work for you, if I'm understanding your needs correctly.  Really, all you need to do is set the colorbox before you begin the call.  The response will determine what you display at that point, with the error callback handling your logic automatically.

```
function Admin_AccountDetails(UserID) {
    $.colorbox({iframe:true, title: "Loading, Please wait", width: "500px", height: "200px", html: "&nbsp;", fastIframe:false });

    var url = "ajax.aspx?ajaxid=3&sid=" + Math.random();
    url = url + "&UserID=" + UserID;

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        success: function(response) {
            $.colorbox({ title: "Account Details (UserID: " + UserID + ")", width: "500px", height: "200px", html: response });
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
            HandleBadAjaxResponse(xhr.status);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Cheers, whilst this lets me use jquery to handle the ajax request it still does not solve the problem of colorbox not showing its loading animation whilst waiting for the ajax to come back :)

Comment: @HeavenCore Sorry, I misunderstood the problem.  It looks like for the colorbox loading animation, you need to set iframe to true.  Give that a shot and see if it makes a difference

Comment: @HeavenCore Also, in regards to your 'syntax error' corrections, that would be the correct syntax for jQuery 1.8+ in most instances

Comment: Hi David, sorry for the late reply, got stuck on another project for a few days. Please see the edit on my question, specifically the two avi's showing what your iframe method produces (not quite right i'm afraid) and the 2nd avi which is almost right apart from a sizing issue - I welcome any ideas you may have.